# how to get rid of certificate error: navigation blocked in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, security-warning

when I access our intranet via https I get this "certificate error: navigation blocked" error in IE8 on Windows XP SP3. I can click `Continue to this website (not recommended).` but I use IE for automation testing so I have to avoid these extra clicks.

Any idea?

I tried

- setting “Turn off the Security Settings Check feature” to enabled.
- setting  "Display Mixed Content" to enabled
- lowering security levels to minimum
- adding the web server address to trusted zone

Comment: Don't know much about disabling it, but i found this, seems it is better to fix the real problem...http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=41859

Comment: Or you might be able to disable it with Group Policy for IE8...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985351.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in IE

1. Click Tools and select Internet
   Options
2. Click the Security
3. Select "Trusted Sites" icon and set the Security level to "Medium Low".
4. Close all the Windows. Then open the browser.

Comment: Thanks Radek.  What are the security implications of doing this?

Comment: That you won't be warned in any case .... Great for automation testing :-) Probably not so good for all users...

Comment: 1. I tried all of the other internet options: advance tab, check server and certificate. 2. I also did vista `regedit` and `HKEY Local MACHINE SOFTWARE` and nothing worked. I used your _internet options advanced tab and uncheck warn about certificate address mismatch, and it worked first time!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to change the security settings for this.

That error message is because your IE is missing a security update, you can follow any of this solutions to fix this without having to change your security settings.

Option 1:

Visit [www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com), go to Security & Updates -> Microsoft Update, then click on "Custom". One of the options on the left-hand navigation pane should be "Software, Optional". Look for "Root Certificate Update" and install that update.

Option 2:

Go to https://ssl.trustwave.com/support/support-root-download.php, click on "STCA" under "PEM Format". The web browser should prompt you to save the file. Save the file in a folder you'll remember. Open that folder and double click on the file you just downloaded (the file is named "stca.crt" by default). A window should come up displaying the details of the certificate. Click on "Install Certificate" on the bottom of the window. The "Certificate Import Wizard" should start. Click "Next" and select "Place all certificates in the following store". Click "Browse" and select "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and click "OK", then "Next", then "Finish".

Option 3:

Visit https://ev.securetrust.com using Microsoft Internet Explorer (IE). Your root certificate should automatically be updated.

Option 4:

If users are part of a policy group, then the administrator can enable "Update Root Certificates" under the policy settings. Windows will then update the root certificates automatically.

Once any of the above options are completed, you should be able to utilize Trustwave SSL certificates without any issues.

Comment: This is not due to IE missing a security update. It is warning you that there is a mismatch between the url being navigating to and the cn / domain associated with the SSL (in an attempt to protect from going to say https://gooogle.com and getting a virus or giving them cc info). For example if I buy an SSL for my website domain.com, I would set the CN to this domain and navigating to `https://domain.com:1234` would be fine, however if I was on the actual server and went to `https://localhost:1234` I would get this error. Same would be true if I used the server's IP instead of the domain name.

Comment: @Despertar We've already experienced this on our company with some clients and IE complaining about the exact same thing. In our case was due to security updates missing in IE. After running the update there was no error message.